# complete css form reset

Tags: html, css, forms, css-reset

So there are a lot of resets out there, and there are a lot of form stylers for cross-browser forms. My issue is that none of the resets I can find fully reset forms!

[Formalize](https://github.com/nathansmith/formalize/blob/master/assets/css/formalize.css) is great, but I want to style it myself from the ground up, where formalize simply has it already styled.

**Is there any reset.css that has full capabilities to reset every form element? If so, where?**

Comment: you can use normalize.css not exactly a reset, but its an easier starting point, as you don't have to know every property, which usually would be a browser-specfic default. apart from that, there is as far as i know, no solution that does not employ javascript, which is able to make forms look similiar cross-browser. the elements are just handled and rendered differently cross-browser, so there is no real css-reset possible.

Comment: Well, If you wan't to resent your form the use simple jquery..
$("form").trigger("reset");

Comment: @UdayHiwarale I'm not resetting the form...I am resetting the browser styling of it

Comment: @hugoderhungrige I am completely okay using javascript, although I don't see how it would help. I just want there to be absolutely 0 styling on any form element. [Using normalize](http://jsfiddle.net/5E8XA/) worked to an extent, it removed margins and all, and I can add getting rid of outline and border, but if you look at the select, select is significantly different in IE (i believe, I don't have it on my local computer) and there is no reset there.

Comment: @RyanSaxe it would mean that you would have to replace every form element by a regular div and that you would define how they behave, store data etc (usually this is done with using hidden form elements). it is what formalize does to some extend. for selects, you can use something like this: http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/

Comment: @hugoderhungrige yes that is what I used to do in situations like this. Now I am using Django, which will create my forms on the fly. It would be fairly exhaustive to write a parser to parse what Django is putting in, then create the correct divs and hide the original form. That would be my last resort

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most informative answer ever but I would strongly recommend creating your own form reset if you can't find one online. A lot of the resets aim to cover just 90% of the browser styling in order to keep code overhead down.

To do it yourself use current resets as inspiration and use the Chrome Inspector tool to find out why a form is styled by default in a particular way and counteract it. Then work with other browsers (with Firebug for Firefox etc) until your form is as consistently styled as possible. You can always add to this reset in future projects if you find things are missing.

If you do decide to create one you should share it on GitHub for others who may need it in the future.